# C++ : Mixing : boost::any + typeid + pointer : clone 'generic' value if it is a pointer

Tags: c++, boost, clone, typeid, typeinfo

Here is what I would like to do:

- From a `boost::any` I would like to know it is a pointer type.
- If it is a pointer, I have to clone it

**Something like this :**

```
boost::any value= new vector<string>();

if (typeid(value).IsPointerType())
{
  boost::any newValue = Clone(value);
}
```

Do you think that it is possible ?

Thanks for your help

NB: I need this for a framework that should be able to initialize Default value.

Comment: `boost::any` papers over design problems. If you're working on a framework/library, you should probably avoid using it.

Comment: I agree with Billy. Try to use another design if possible. Maybe `boost::variant` will fit your purpose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the type_info interface:

```
#include <boost/any.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    boost::any intVal = 5;

    int* a = new int(6);
    boost::any ptrVal = a;

    cout << intVal.type().__is_pointer_p() <<endl;
    cout << ptrVal.type().__is_pointer_p() << endl; 

    return 0;
}
```

Returns

```
0
1
```

Comment: There [is no such thing](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/typeinfo/type_info/) as `std::type_info::__is_pointer_p()`. You are probably looking at some compiler-specific internals.

Comment: @Georg: True - GCC only extension.

Comment: how about ends_with(val.type().name(), "*")? Might have to strip const, but other than that, it should work (although the standard is probably not very specific on this).

Comment: @ltjax: the string returned by `name()` is implementation-dependent, no way to you use it without knowledge of the compilers naming-scheme.

Comment: I thought so. Still, it might be a valuable option on compilers that don't support __is_pointer_p, but still return a meaningful string with name().

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like this (didn't compile it):

```
#include <boost/type_traits.hpp>

class any_p: public boost::any {
    const bool is_ptr_;
public:
    template<class T>
    any_p(T obj): boost::any(obj), is_ptr_(is_pointer<T>::value_type) {}
    const bool is_ptr() const { return is_ptr_; }
};
```